# Reordering not working for multiple values of a field in draggable views

Tags: views

I have a requirement in my project, reordering of draggable view items and after reordering and saving, the top row of the views should be transfered or carried to the next page.

Unfortunately i cannot do this because the view items are multiple values of a field which is a delta field. Please help me in this issue.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: which drupal version are you using?

Comment: I am using drupal 7.21,actually my issue is able to  reorder cck delta values in dragabble views but reordered values are not saving as i reordered .